# Confusion with IntPtr and Marshaling to a structure

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, marshalling, intptr

I am taking to Objective C code and turning it into C# code for my Xamarin iOS project.

I am taking a UIImage and trying to get the pixels in order to get the RGB values so that I can print the image on a receipt.

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
public struct ARGBPixel {
            public byte alpha;
            public byte red;
            public byte green;
            public byte blue;
        };
```

I have some code (courtesy of [here](http://www.techques.com/question/1-2597198/Retrieving-a-pixel-alpha-value-for-a-UIImage-%28MonoTouch%29)) that will take a UIImage and return a pointer to data like so:

```
protected CGBitmapContext CreateARGBBitmapContext(CGImage inImage)
{
    var pixelsWide = inImage.Width;
    var pixelsHigh = inImage.Height;
    var bitmapBytesPerRow = pixelsWide * 4;
    var bitmapByteCount = bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh;
    //Note implicit colorSpace.Dispose() 
    using(var colorSpace = CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB())
    {
        //Allocate the bitmap and create context
        var bitmapData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bitmapByteCount);
        //I think this is unnecessary, as I believe Marshal.AllocHGlobal will throw OutOfMemoryException
        if(bitmapData == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception("Memory not allocated.");
        }

        var context = new CGBitmapContext(bitmapData, pixelsWide, pixelsHigh, 8,
            bitmapBytesPerRow, colorSpace, CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst);
        if(context == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Context not created");
        }
        return context;
    }
}

//Store pixel data as an ARGB Bitmap
protected IntPtr RequestImagePixelData(UIImage inImage)
{
    var imageSize = inImage.Size;
    CGBitmapContext ctxt = CreateARGBBitmapContext(inImage.CGImage);
    var rect = new RectangleF(0.0f, 0.0f, imageSize.Width, imageSize.Height);
    ctxt.DrawImage(rect, inImage.CGImage);
    var data = ctxt.Data;
    return data;
}
```

After I get the data back, I want to marshal each element in the data array to an `ARGBPixel` by doing this:

```
ARGBPixel argbpixel = //stuck here
```

The code looks like this:

```
private NSData GetMiniData(UIImage image)
{
    NSMutableData commands = new NSMutableData ();

    int width = (int)image.Size.Width;
    int height = (int)image.Size.Height;

    var pixels = RequestImagePixelData (image);

    int w = width / 8;
    if ((width % 8) != 0)
        w++;
    int mWidth = w * 8;

    int byteWidth = mWidth / 8;

    commands.AppendBytes (new byte[]{ 0x1b, 0x40 });

    byte totalRowCount = 0;

    while (totalRowCount < height) {
        byte[] data = new byte[sizeof(byte) * byteWidth * 24];

        UInt32 pos = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < 24; y++) {
            if (totalRowCount < height) {
                for (byte x = 0; x < byteWidth; x++) {
                    int bits = 8;

                    if ((x == byteWidth - 1) && (width < mWidth)) {
                        bits = 8 - (mWidth - width);
                    }

                    byte work = 0x00;

                    for (byte xbit = 0; xbit < bits; xbit++) {
                        work <<= 1;
                        byte[] dataBytes = new byte[2048];
                        Marshal.Copy (pixels, dataBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32 (2048));

                        //ARGBPixel argbpixel = MarshalPixel (dataBytes [PixelIndex ((byte)(xbit + x * 8), totalRowCount, (byte)width)]);
                        //Marshal.PtrToStructure(dataBytes[PixelIndex ((byte)(xbit + x * 8), totalRowCount, (byte)width)], typeof(ARGBPixel));

                        var pix = 255;


                        if (PixelBrightness(argbpixel.red, argbpixel.green, argbpixel.blue) < 127)
                        {
                            work |= 0x01;
                        }

                    }

                    data [pos++] = work;
                }
            }

            totalRowCount++;
        }

        NSMutableData command = null;

        /*if (true) {

            command = SMPort.GenerateBitImageCommand (byteWidth, 24, data, "mini");
        }*/

        if (command != null) {
            commands.AppendData (command);
        } else {
            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[]{ 0x1b, 0x58, 0x34, 0, 24 }; // [ESC X 4]

            imageBytes [3] = (byte) byteWidth;

            commands.AppendBytes (imageBytes);

            commands.AppendBytes (data);

            byte[] printBytes = new byte[] { 0x1b, 0x58, 0x32, 24 };

            commands.AppendBytes (printBytes);
        }

        //free(data);
    }

    byte[] endingBytes = new byte[]{ 0x0c, 0x1b, 0x4A, 0x78 };

    commands.AppendBytes (endingBytes);

    //free(pixels);

    return NSData.FromBytes (commands.Bytes, commands.Length);

    //[someData release];

    //return imageData;


}

public ARGBPixel MarshalPixel(byte[] bytes)
{
    GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc (bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);

    ARGBPixel pix = (ARGBPixel)Marshal.PtrToStructure (handle.AddrOfPinnedObject (), typeof(ARGBPixel));
    handle.Free ();
    return pix;
}
```

And more code here:

```
byte PixelBrightness(byte red, byte green, byte blue)
{
    int level = ((int)red + (int)green + (int)blue)/3;
        return (byte)level;
}

UInt32 PixelIndex(UInt32 x, UInt32 y, UInt32 width)
{
    return (UInt32)(x + (y * width));
}
```

I am completely confused at this point. I just want to be able to get the pixels in order to tell what the brightness is and that would determine the next sequence in my array of bytes to feed as commands to my printer...

If this helps...here is the objective c code I am trying to change in order to work with my Xamarin application:

```
- (NSData *)getImageMiniDataForPrinting:(BOOL)compressionEnable pageModeEnable:(BOOL)pageModeEnable
{
    if (imageData != nil)
    {
        return imageData;
    }

    CGImageRef cgImage = [m_image CGImage];
    int32_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
    int32_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);

    ARGBPixel * pixels = malloc(width * height * sizeof(ARGBPixel));
    ManipulateImagePixelData(cgImage, pixels);

    if (ditheringSupported == true)
    {
        ConvertToMonochromeSteinbertDithering(pixels, width, height, 1.5);
    }

    if (pixels == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    int w = width / 8;
    if ((width % 8) != 0)
        w++;
    int mWidth = w * 8;

    int byteWidth = mWidth / 8;

    NSMutableData *someData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    if (pageModeEnable)
    {
        u_int8_t beginingBytes[] = {0x1b, 0x40,
                                    0x1b, 0x4c,
//                                  0x1b, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, mWidth % 256, mWidth / 256,  height       % 256,  height       / 256,
                                    0x1b, 0x57, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, mWidth % 256, mWidth / 256, (height + 50) % 256, (height + 50) / 256,
                                    0x1b, 0x58, 0x32, 0x18};

        [someData appendBytes:beginingBytes length:2 + 2 + 10 + 4];
    }
    else
    {
        u_int8_t beginingBytes[] = {0x1b, 0x40};

        [someData appendBytes:beginingBytes length:2];
    }

    int totalRowCount = 0;

    while (totalRowCount < height)
    {
        u_int8_t *data = malloc(sizeof(u_int8_t) * byteWidth * 24);

        memset(data, 0, sizeof(u_int8_t) * byteWidth * 24);

        uint32_t pos = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < 24; y++)
        {
            if (totalRowCount < height)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < byteWidth; x++)
                {
                    int bits = 8;

                    if ((x == byteWidth - 1) && (width < mWidth))
                    {
                        bits = 8 - (mWidth - width);
                    }

                    u_int8_t work = 0x00;

                    for (int xbit = 0; xbit < bits; xbit++)
                    {
                        work <<= 1;

                        ARGBPixel pixel = pixels[PixelIndex(xbit + x * 8, totalRowCount, width)];

                        if (PixelBrightness(pixel.red, pixel.green, pixel.blue) < 127)
                        {
                            work |= 0x01;
                        }
                    }

                    data[pos++] = work;
                }
            }

            totalRowCount++;
        }

        NSMutableData *command = nil;

        if (compressionEnable)
        {
            NSString *portSettings = @"mini";

            command = [SMPort generateBitImageCommand:byteWidth :24 :data :portSettings];
        }

        if (command != nil)
        {
            [someData appendData:command];

            [command release];
        }
        else
        {
            u_int8_t imageBytes[] = {0x1b, 0x58, 0x34, 0, 24}; // [ESC X 4]

            imageBytes[3] = byteWidth;

            [someData appendBytes:imageBytes length:5];

            [someData appendBytes:data length:sizeof(u_int8_t) * byteWidth * 24];

            u_int8_t printBytes[] = {0x1b, 0x58, 0x32, 24};

            [someData appendBytes:printBytes length:4];
        }

        free(data);
    }

    u_int8_t endingBytes[] = {0x0c,
                              0x1b, 0x4A, 0x78};

    [someData appendBytes:endingBytes length:1 + 3];

    free(pixels);

    imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:[someData mutableBytes] length:[someData length]];

    [someData release];

    return imageData;
}

u_int8_t PixelBrightness(u_int8_t red, u_int8_t green, u_int8_t blue)
{
    int level = ((int)red + (int)green + (int)blue)/3;
    return level;
}

u_int32_t PixelIndex(u_int32_t x, u_int32_t y, u_int32_t width)
{
    return (x + (y * width));
}
```

My question is how do I get the array of structures (pixels) from the pointer - So I want to change a point into an array of structures?

Comment: I cannot see the question

Comment: I edited the question. I want to know whether I am able to get the pixels from the pointer and how I would do it.

Comment: You already have the pointer to the data, it is returned by RequestImagePixels, that is an IntPtr that points to the data.   You can either use Marshal.ReadXXX methods, or cast to a byte * and manipulate it that way.